# SeekBar progress update redraws whole ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a view template which consists of main `RelativeLayout` and 2 `FrameLayouts` which are used for fragments.(I have attached an image to visualize my template.) Red is `RelativeLayout`, brown and green are `FrameLayouts`.

Now, the brown part contains a very heavy but beautiful grid list. The green part contains a simple `LinearLayout` with `Image`(gray), `Seekbar`(Blue) and a `TextView`(Pink).

The `SeekBar` progress is updated on the UI-thread every 1 second. I have noticed that ever 1 second the scrolling of the grid list freezes. By doing some traceview debugging I noticed that the list is re-drawn every 1 second.

On top of that, I enabled "Show layout updates" option on the actual device from Developers menu. It showed even more interesting view - everything above the `Seekbar` gets redrawn. Why is SeekBar view update redraws all views above?

I cannot show much of the code, but I do standard Fragment attachment and then create a thread in the fragment with a specific sleep period and then updating the seekbar progress on ui-thread.

Let me know if you need any more information and I will try to update the thread. I spent like 4-5 hours today trying to understand why is it doing that - with no success...

The main template is very simple. Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgwood"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/top_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container" />



<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#ff111111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

EDIT: Some more information...

The bottom fragment (green) contains something like the following view structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/player_playercontainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_player"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hdd" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.64"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="#cc111111"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#888"
            android:textSize="13dp" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100" />


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Attaching fragment to the bottom layout:

```
if (bundle == null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();  
        SourceListFragment fragment = BottomFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.bottom_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Updating the seekbar in the fragment:

```
/* Called every 1 sec */
void updateCallback(final int progress) {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        if (seekBarView == null) {
            seekBarView = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        } 
        seekBarView.setProgress()
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code or which methods are used to update your Seekbar? The template you've provided doesn't show anything out of the ordinary, but your description of the three objects in the `LinearLayout` is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Applying the ViewHolder pattern in your list would decrease the redrawing time. I know that it does not solve your problem but it could be a handy technique. http://vsvydenko.blogspot.nl/2011/06/android-use-viewholder.html

Comment: @Bram I already have ViewHolder, and I recycle the list views as well. But thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Jon I have added more information. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I doubt this is it, but have you tried testing it without a background in your RelativeLayout? I think ListViews can act weird with them sometimes due to an optimization android has.

Comment: That's not the case as well :(

Comment: Is that your real layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the TextView width was set to wrap_content and therefore it was redrawn every time the value updates. The thing is if a child element is redrawn, ie that TextView, then all parent views will be forces to redraw as well.

So basically, set dynamic views either to a specific size or to match_parent.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot show much of the code, but I do standard Fragment attachment
>   and then create a thread in the fragment with a specific sleep period
>   and then updating the seekbar progress on ui-thread.

Try using a `Handler` to update the `ProgressBar`:

Define the following global variables:

```
Handler updateHandler;

// loop control variable
boolean shouldStop;

Runnable updateRunnable;
```

Initialize variables:

```
updateHandler = new Handler();

shouldStop = false;

updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!shouldStop) {

            // Post this Runnable again with a delay of 1000 milliseconds
            updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);

            // Update ProgressBar
            updateCallback(Your_Progress_Value);
        }
    }
};

// Start the update process
updateHandler.post(updateRunnable);
```

And you do not need to specify the thread to run the update on in this case:

```
/* Called every 1 sec */
void updateCallback(final int progress) {
    if (seekBarView == null) {
        seekBarView = (SeekBar) view.findElementById(R.id.progressBar);
    } 
    seekBarView.setProgress(...);
}
```

The `boolean` variable `shouldStop` will be used when you need to end the update process. Set it to `true` and the updates will stop.

Note: You have a `ProgressBar` widget in your layout and your code uses a `SeekBar`. Could you make that correction in your post? Another thing, there's no method with signature `findElementById(int)` in `View`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Sorry, I trimmed few things and mistyped `findElementById` from JavaScript. I will try to use the handler, but I don't really see what difference will it make.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what it's doing, by using `android:layout_above` your top fragment is drawn after the bottom. So it is affected by the bottom one being updated.

Using `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` instead should prevent this.

If you haven't seen it yet you should definitely check out the [I/O talk about custom views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA). RelativeLayouts can be a nightmare to work with but they did an excellent job explaining how they work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgwood"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/top_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"  />



<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#ff111111"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work, sorry. I even tried changing the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. I believe it might be something other than the ui template. Probably some Activity configurations...